# Using Count function in SOQL and If condition

Tags: count

I am updating a value on related record based on the count of another record. The condition is say A is lookup to B record. So, if there is only one B record then certain Value of a field say C on B record will be populated to a new field in A record.

Comment: Was trying to check condition directly using COUNT(), but that's wrong. So, I am storing the count in a variable and trying to check with that variable

Answer (score 1):

There are no conditional statements (such as `IF()`) in SOQL, and you can't put an aggregate function like `COUNT()` in the `WHERE` clause, so you'll need to do at least some of the processing in Apex.

I don't think the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary Tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) is a fit for you in this case, because I don't know if it allows you to restrict the 'rollup' based on a count.

That aside, there are a couple of queries that can accomplish what you want.

First, using aggregate functions:

```
[SELECT Object_A__c, Field_C__c, COUNT(Id) number_of_B_records FROM Object_B__c GROUP BY Object_A__c, Field_C__c]
```

Second, using Parent-Child subquery:

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Field_C__c FROM Object_B__r) FROM Object_A__c]
```

In the end, there's not much of a difference between these two queries. The only appreciable difference is in the Apex to process each query.

For the first query (n.b. You'll need to manually cast the value from `ar.get('Field_C__c')`):

```
List<Object_A__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<Object_A__c>();
for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT Object_A__c, Field_C__c, COUNT(Id) number_of_B_records FROM Object_B__c GROUP BY Object_A__c, Field_C__c]){
    if((Integer)ar.get('number_of_B_records') == 1){
        recordsToUpdate.add(new Object_A__c(
            Id = (Id)ar.get('Object_A__c'),
            Field_To_Update__c = ar.get('Field_C__c')
        );
    }
}
```

For the second query:

```
List<Object_A__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<Object_A__c>();
for(Object_A__c a_rec :[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Field_C__c FROM Object_B__r) FROM Object_A__c]){
    if(a_rec.Object_B__r.size() == 1){
        recordsToUpdate.add(new Object_A__c(
            Id = a_rec.Id,
            Field_To_Update__c = a_rec.Object_B__r[0].Field_C__c
        );
    }
}
```

Either one could be used in a trigger for either object, or in a separate Apex class.

If you do use this as a base for a trigger on `Object_A__c`, you'd want to have this snippet execute `Before Update`. You'd also want to modify the snippet to make use of `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.newMap` to avoid using a DML statement.